# get back from browser to app

Tags: ios, safari

I have a app that I have to open safari for a payment and when it's done I want to back to app. is there any way to do this in iOS?I searched a lot there was a lot of examples for android but nothing useful for IOS.
after payment the last page would be : "https://madyar.org/BackToApp".I want when safari goes to this link, safari exits or hide and my app open again.
any advice?

Comment: You need that last page to open a URL associated with your app. E.g. "MyCoolApp://"

Comment: I suggest you to search Universal Links. https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/ 

But for payment issues i think redirect to safari is not useful. Why don’t you use WKWebView for this ?

Comment: @Paulw11 for Omid's sake those are called "URL Schemes" just so he knows what to google.

Comment: Yeah, I was having a brain freeze moment

Comment: @U.Benlice redirecting to Safari for payment is perfectly fine. What is needed here (as others already mentioned) that the payment provider knows the url scheme of the app.

Comment: I know about URL Scheme. But my customer saying it must be back to app with this address only, can I see the web page address that the user is seeing in WKWebView? @U.Benlice

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer. I didn't get it exactly. If you mean address bar,  there isn't  bar in wkwebview like Safari or SfSafariViewController unless you develop custom ui components. But of course you can see and set the url's that user seeing inside your code.